# 3D Terrain goes black in Unity, How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unity3d-terrain

My problem is, that if I try to use a brush in unity I move the cursor over the terrain, it turns black.
I tried: Turning off auto generate lightning, re-loading the project.
Can you help me please, how can I fix this?
Data: OS: OS X 10.11.6

### Version: 2019.2.7f2

Also an error I get: RenderTexture.Create failed: format unsupported for random writes - R16 SFloat (45).

### UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

[Problem Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjVst.png)

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? Having a similar problem on Linux when building for a Windows target

Comment: Unfortunately no, because I didn't use Unity for terrain, it was just an experiment. But if you find a fix, then please write it down. I think it's because my old mac. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unity only supports [macOS 10.12 and later.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/system-requirements.html) You will have to use a version of the editor from that era.

Also, I don't think Unity tests with the NVIDIA web drivers on hackintoshes at all. In my experience they are quite glitchy.

Comment: Can you please tell me which is the latest release of Unity, that supports macOS 10.11.6? I can't find it, thanks for the answer!